# Pinterest Authentication url returning 404 error?

Tags: php, json, oauth, pinterest

I am testing pinterest api 
http://pinterest.com/developers/api/

here on above url in authentication section it says i have to redirect users to pinterest Authentication screen.
but when i redirect users o this url(with my client_id and redirect_url)

```
https://pinterest.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=12345456&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI&scope=read
```

it returns 404 error?
what is wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the response I received from them the other day:

> Hello Chris, the API was not really opened for public consumption. We pushed the docs live in an attempt to get feedback but we had to shut it down since we saw activity. We will write back the people who signed up for the beta list when we are ready.
>
> Please fill out this form to get on the beta list.
>
> https://docs.google.com/a/pinterest.com/spreadsheet/viewform?hl=en_US&formkey=dHBvVkVsN2NzUVEybDhjeFZ0ZzFKWnc6MQ

I wish they'd note this on the docs.